# Transforming rows to columns using Amazon Glue

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, data-transform

I'm using AWS Glue to transform a set of data which have multiple rows based on one column's value. I am trying to pivot the data and reduce the number of rows.

I believe I can use Amazon Glue for this. But, this is my first time using Glue. I'm struggling to figure out a good way to do this. Some of the pySpark-extension Transformations look promising (perhaps, "Map" or "Relationalize"). What is the good way?

For example :

```
primary_key|key|value
12345|is_male|1
12345|is_college_educated|0
```

to

```
primary_key|is_male|is_college_educated
12345|1|0
```